# Is there any way to make git not commit a special file anymore?

Tags: git, commit

Sometimes, I don't want to commit a special file after the first commit, for example conn.php which contain my mysql username and password, I can change it at first and commit it, and change it back, but did I must do this cycle each time I commit?

I believe there is are some solutions? What are they?

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)? ;)

Comment: So I need to change my .gitignore to .gitignore_global?

Comment: Only if you want to ignore the files in _every_ git repository on your computer.

Comment: I believe this:`git update-index --assume-unchanged conn.php` is the best (easy to understand).

Answer (score 0):

Add the files to a file called `.gitignore` in your project folder as explained [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: I add it before the first commit, and then commit it, and then change the username and password in it, and then if I use `git add .` it will be commit again? (although it is in the `.gitignore`)

Answer (score 0):

For ignoring changes to a file, the best option is to use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged conn.php
```

which will update the index, marking this file as not updated (and thus will not try to add it to the new commits).